# SQL Syntax help

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

What would be the SQL syntax to select 4 different columns in a single row in a table, add those together and then insert that value into a 5th different column in the same row? The columns are all numeric(11,2).

For example- Table name is DataCheck
there is an ID that is primary key so how do I select col1, col2, col3, col4 where ID = 232...etc and add them up, and insert into col4 where id = 232...etc

Comment: Are you trying to update a 5th column in the table or just return a 5th calculated column in your query result?

Comment: In general, you don't want to store calculated values.  You will have to update the stored calculated total anytime the value of one of the operands changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET col5 = col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 WHERE id = 232
```

Answer (score 2):

Errr....it doesn't get much simpler than the obvious:

```
update myTable
set column5 = column1
            + column2
            + column3
            + column4
            + column5
where <some-where-clause>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing the calculated value in the same row?

Generally you shold not store the same data twice (in columns 1,2,3,4 and column 5). If somehow they are not equal, how will you know which column is correct?

Answer (score -1):

This update statement should solve your problem.

```
update table set col5 = col4 + col3 + col2 + col1
```

Comment: if you want all rows updated you don't need to do it row by row with id

Answer (score -1):

Complete guess - but does this work?

UPDATE DataCheck SET col5=(col1+col2+col3+col4)